# Set time formatting on a datetime index when plotting Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, timestamp

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a DatetimeIndex with a monthly (`M`) frequency. However, when I plot a column from this Dataframe the labels on my plot show a date and time even though these bits are meaningless. How can I fix this so that a month is only displaying in `YYYY-MM` format?

[image: picture of problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a small modification to your `DateTimeIndex` before plotting by converting them to `PeriodIndex` and providing a monthly frequency, like so -

```
a.index = a.index.to_period('M')  # Even a.index.astype('period[M]') works
```

---

***Demo:***

Consider a `DF` as shown:

```
idx = pd.date_range('2016/1/1', periods=10, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(count=np.random.randint(10,1000,10)), idx).rename_axis('start_date')
df
```

[image]

Old `DateTimeIndex`:

```
>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-31', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-30',
               '2016-05-31', '2016-06-30', '2016-07-31', '2016-08-31',
               '2016-09-30', '2016-10-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='start_date', freq='M')
```

New `PeriodIndex`:

```
>>> df.index = df.index.to_period('M')
>>> df.index
PeriodIndex(['2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04', '2016-05', '2016-06',
             '2016-07', '2016-08', '2016-09', '2016-10'],
            dtype='period[M]', name='start_date', freq='M')
```

Plot them:

```
df['count'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]